# SQL Server Case Statement- Deriving one column from two others when grouping by transactions

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to apply make a flag based on the below scenario. The source table and desired results I am after are in the tables below.

When `SRCE_SYST_FLAG` isn't null (and `= Y`), then create a new flag (`DERIVED_FLAG`) using the value in the `SRCE_SYST_FLAG` column, else use the `GENERIC_FLAG` column.

However if another record in the same `TRAN_ID` group has the `SRCE_SYST_FLAG` column populated, set the `DERIVED_FLAG` to the other `SRCE_SYST_F`. This is the case in `TRAN_ID = 2222` below.

Would anyone know how to do this using a case statement? I can make a generic one such as the one below, but this doesn't use the `SRCE_SYST_FLAG` for the records that are NULL but the `SRCE_SYST_FLAG` is populated for another record in that tran_id group  :

```
CASE
   WHEN SRCE_SYST_Flag = 'Y' 
      THEN SRCE_SYST_FLAG 
      ELSE GENERIC_FLAG
END AS 'DERIVED_FLAG'
```

Sample data set:

```
Client | Limit        | Pdct_type_c |  SRCE_SYST_FLAG | GENERIC_FLAG |  TRAN_ID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John   | 4,000,000.00 | DCO         |  y              | N            | 2222
John   |              | DCO         |  NULL           | N            | 2222
Mark   | 2,000,000.00 | DCO         |  NULL           | N            | 435
Mark   |              | DCO         |  NULL           | N            | 435
Luke   | 4,000,000.00 | DCO         |  N              | Y            | 980
```

Desired result:

```
Client | Limit        | Pdct_type_c | DERIVED_FLAG |  TRAN_ID 
---------------------------------------------------------------
John   | 4,000,000.00 | DCO         | Y            | 2222
John   |              | DCO         | Y            | 2222
Mark   | 2,000,000.00 | DCO         | N            | 435
Mark   |              | DCO         | N            | 435
Luke   | 4,000,000.00 | DCO         | Y            | 980
```

I appreciate any assistance,

Cheers

Comment: You should show us data covering all possible cases.

Comment: What should happen when `SRCE_SYST_FLAG = 'N' and GENERIC_FLAG  = 'Y`' instead of first record for `TRAN_ID = 2222`

Comment: If source syst flag is not 'Y' then set DERIVED_FLAG to GENERIC_FLAG value. I will update the above information

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM OVER` to count the number of 'Y' per tran_id:

```
select client
, limit
, Pdct_type_c
, TRAN_ID
, case when SUM(case when SRCE_SYST_FLAG = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (partition by tran_id) > 0 then 'Y' else GENERIC_FLAG end DERIVED_FLAG
from table
```